# MXNet: Are there python api to get some op`s name

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

I want to see what is the op's **type/name** of one `Symbol in MXNet`.
e.g:

```
c = mxnet.symbol.Convolution()
```

`type(c)` --> will print this symbol is Convolution or others like Pooling etc.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols are just registered as functions in python. You can get its name by calling the `__name__` attribute. e.g

```
>>> mxnet.symbol.Convolution.__name__
'Convolution'
```

Hope this helps!